# TypeScript is complaining about missing component in React Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Im trying to use Accordion in Bootstrap React but Visual Studio Code is complaining that it cant find it.

[image]

As the docs states I only needed to include a import of Accordion?

What I imported: `import { Col, Row, Container, Form, Accordion } from "react-bootstrap";`

How can I fix this? It's not possible to import Accordion.Header for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using them as classes?

example: class="accordion-header". Give it a try.

Didn't found anything on their docs.

Or

something like this: import { Col, Row, Container, Form, Accordion: { Body, Header} } from "react-bootstrap";

Sorry for making it as an anwser, i can't make comments yet

Comment: That might work, but again the compiler is complaining about the div tag for the Item, is there a way I can put eventKey in there somehow? eventKey="0" gives me the error: Property 'eventKey' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>'. I've tried your import string too but did not work

Comment: Doesn't it need a toogle? check this out https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/use-bootstrap-accordion-with-react